# Could not download Artifact

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently started developing Android Apps in Android studio. When i started new project it comes with an error.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not download artifact 'support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.0)'
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/24.2.0/support-core-ui-24.2.0.aar'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

Can anyone help how to fix this?

Comment: You need to disable gradle offline mode to be able to download the updated version of gradle-core. 

Type Ctrl+Shift+A, then "offline", and you should see the option in the list

Comment: That worked but came with New error, could not resolve symbol R..

Comment: Go to File>Project Structure Check i If not selected, choose the Project app module.

Comment: Under the Properties tab, in the Compile Sdk Version field, choose the latest SDK In the Build Tools Version field, choose the latest version.
Click OK.Now Refresh and Sync Gradle Files

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate.. It worked

Comment: @Glad you sorted out..